Code: 19 16 19 15 23 16 24 11 11 24
Here's a message I have created:
19 16 19 15 23 16 24 11 11 24. 25 19 25 19 15 16 11 16. 25 19 25 19 15 25 16 26 19 26 '24 12 25 12. 26 19 26 15 19 29 23 25 23 25 16 30. 12 25 12 19 29 14 11 14 25 16 30. 12 25 12, 11 14 11, 26 19 26, 11 23 25, 21 19 25, 11 30 11 22 11 24 14 12 15 12 15. 11 22 19 29 26 25 26 25 16 30. 11 22 19 29 14 11 14 25 16 25 12, 30 25 25. 12 15 12 15 19 29 24 11 24 1 25 16 30. 12 15 12 15 19 29 23 25 23 25 16 12 25 12, 30 25 25. 30 25 30, 25 19 30, 11 22, 12 15 12 15, 26 19 26, 11 22 24 14 12 15 12 15. 26 19 26, 11 23 25, 17 25 30, 25 11 22 '24 12 15 12 15. 21 19 30, 11 20 20, 11 22 11 24 14 15 25 26 25. 12 25 12, 11 14 11, 17 25 30 15 1 22 '24 12 15 12 25, 30 25 25. 12 15 12 15, 11 24 1, 19 29 1 30 1 22 1 24 14 15 25 25, 11 22, 26 19 26, 25 19 19, 12 15 12, 19 11 24 14, 11 22 1 12 1 30 12 24 15 15.
This took lots of thought, although I don't think I have made an encoded text that will stump anyone.
Hint:

 The numbers correspond, not to letters, but something else that may repeat.


Hello, welcome to PSE. Your puzzle doesn't break any rules, but I would recommend having a read of this meta post: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do

What does the [tag:formation-of-numbers] tag signify?

@codewarrior0 I fixed it, so now it's a number sequence instead.

Your hint tells me this is not a cipher, but a code; each number stands for a word or phrase.  There must be some book or document which acts as a codebook for this code, telling us what each number stands for. How are we meant to find out what it is? Are we expected to recognize the plaintext outright using only the punctuation and then work backwards to recover the codebook?
